# Curvature of the curve on the unit sphere if torsion is always 1.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, curvature

Let $I$ be an open interval, $\gamma:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a curve which is parameterized by arc length and $\gamma(s)$ is in unit sphere for all $s\in I$, and $\tau$ be the torsion of $\gamma$.

Now, I want to prove below;

If $\tau(s)=1$ for all $s\in I$, then there exists some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle{\kappa(s)=\frac{1}{a\sin s+b\cos s}}$. Note that $\kappa(s)$ is curvature of $\gamma$.

I try to prove it by　calculating according to the definition, but formula is too complicated and doesn't work well...

Comment: Have you tried using Frenet's formulas?

Comment: Yes, I have. I got $\kappa(s)^2=||\gamma''(s)||=(x''(s))^2+(y''(s))^2+(z''(s))^2$ from definition of torsion, but I don't know what to do from here...

Comment: Well.. you also know that $x(s)^2+y(s)^2+z(s)^2=1$. You should derive consequences from that as well.